# Trigger tooltip 'labelColor' callback in Angular test

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jestjs, chart.js

I use `chart.js` tooltip in my app.

In order to set some styling on the tooltip, I use the `labelColor` callback;

```
callbacks: {
 labelColor: () => {
  return {
     backgroundColor: '#ed0453'
  }
 }
}
```

Now I want to test that my background color actually is what I expected:

```
it('should have the expected color', () => { 
     // trigger labelColor callback here
     expect(chart.options.plugins.tooltip.something.backgroundColor).tobe('#ed0453');
 });

How can I do this?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could access to the tooltip object, instead of the tooltip configuration.

In the tooltip object (`chart.tooltip`), there is an array `labelColors`, with all label color objects.

```
expect(chart.tooltip.labelColors[0].backgroundColor).tobe('#ed0453');
```

Comment: Yes, but this value won`t be set until the callback is fired, which is the core of my issue; How do I trigger the callback fired when you hover a line in the chart, in a test

Comment: The "callbacks " of tooltip are not SCRIPTABLE options: See CHART.JS code: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/3fea72e81cd3442f25eb50823e01d54a9b80f733/src/plugins/plugin.tooltip.js#L1325-L1328

Comment: But I don´t want to call the function, i want to trigger the event which calls the callback

Comment: Ok, therefore I think you need to simulate a "nouseover" event on the chart and tooltip will be invoked and then the the callback will be invoked. Maybe you can see how the community is testing the tooltip and callbacks invocation: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/test/specs/plugin.tooltip.tests.js